# How to convert mysql query to laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Here my sql code:**

```
SELECT favorites.id_user, specialities.specialities, university_datas.university_name 
FROM 
(
    (
        (
            favorites INNER JOIN programs ON programs.id=favorites.id_program
        ) 
        INNER JOIN specialities ON programs.id_specialities=specialities.id
    )
    INNER JOIN university_datas ON programs.id_univer=university_datas.id
) 

WHERE id_user=2;
```

I try with phpmyadmin and i get needed result but I can't convert to laravel

Comment: Wait. what? Your question is unclear. SQL is a programming language. laravel is a framwork. Do you mean how you perform sql-request in the laravel framework?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, show us. If no, read the manual and make some attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$get_fav = DB::table('favorites')
->join('programs', 'favorites.id_program', '=', 'programs.id')
->join('specialities','programs.id_specialities', '=','specialities.id' )
->join('university_datas','programs.id_univer','=', 'university_datas.id')
->where('favorites.id_user', Auth::user()->id)
->select('favorites.id_user', 'specialities.specialities', 'university_datas.university_name')
->get();
```